# Orderby() on observablecollections in silverlight does not work

Tags: sorting, observablecollection

My code is,

```
DestMenu.Add(SelectedMenu);
ObservableCollection<MenuModel> temp = 
(ObservableCollection<MenuModel>)DestMenu.OrderBy(p =>(p.MenuName));
DestMenu = temp;
```

Here, SelectedMenu is the new item to be added to collection. temp is dummy collection to swap. And, when i try to convert the sorted collection, if any, to ObservableCollection, it throws some exception.

Can someone help me sort the collection and make me understand the problem in my code?

Thanks 
Manikandan

Answer (score 1):

I got the trick.

```
DestMenu.Add(SelectedMenu);
IEnumerable<MenuModel> temp = DestMenu.OrderBy(p =>(p.MenuName));
DestMenu = new ObservableCollection<MenuModel>(temp);
```

This works and the DestMenu has the sorted collection now.

Thanks
Manikandan

Comment: Kindly let me know, if you have some other good option, please.

Answer (score 0):

Well so sad that the OrderBy Extension Method doesn't sort the collection but returns an IOrderdEnumerable so to handle this you should do the following

```
DestMenu = new ObservableCollection<MenuModel>(DestMenu.OrderBy(o=>o.MenuName));
```

Of course using ObservableCollection you need items to be updated on the view that wont actually happened when you use this approach of sorting because ObservableCollection updates items on the view because it fires CollectionChanged Event but in fact we have changed the Collection itself not an element within the collection so it would be good if you did the following

```
public YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  void YourMethod()
   {
      DestMenu = new ObservableCollection<MenuModel>(DestMenu.OrderBy(o=>o.MenuName));
      RaisePropertyChanged("DestMenu");
   }


  event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
  {
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
  }
```